# deploy with capistrano failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have a capistrano taks like this

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "cloudoc"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:luizkowalski/cloudoc.git"

set :scm, :git

role :web, "xx.xx.xx.xxx" 
role :app, "xx.xx.xx.xxx" 
role :db,  "xx.xx.xx.xxx", :primary => true

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, true

set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

role :web, "xx.xx.xx.xxx"
role :app, "xx.xx.xx.xxx"
role :db, "xx.xx.xx.xxx", :primary => true
```

after the `cap deploy` this is the output.
for some reason, he fails and I don't know why. I've tried with use_sudo false and with root, same thing happen.

```
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 4714ms
    copying the cached version to /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144
  * executing "cp -RPp /home/deploy/shared/cached-copy /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144 && (echo 61eeff328c40e104962f96bf6ffc5150bd1162e4 > /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/REVISION)"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 604ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public/assets &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/shared/assets &&\\\n        ln -s /home/deploy/shared/assets /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public/assets"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 544ms
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/Gemfile --path /home/deploy/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1990ms
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1042ms
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/log /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public/system /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/tmp"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 534ms
  * executing "ln -s /home/deploy/shared/system /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/public/system"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 517ms
  * executing "ln -s /home/deploy/shared/log /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/log"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 519ms
  * executing "ln -s /home/deploy/shared/pids /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 521ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled jquery.js  (2ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js  (0ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled twitter/bootstrap.js  (247ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled ios-checkboxes/ios-checkboxes.js  (20642ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled ios-checkboxes.js  (22403ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled rails.validations.js  (418ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled best_in_place.js  (327ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled autosize.js  (76ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled bootstrap.js  (5870ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled dashboard.js  (1388ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled documents.js  (896ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled home.js  (377ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled sessions.js  (563ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Compiled application.js  (51370ms)  (pid 1075)
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xx.xxx] Killed
    command finished in 68972ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144; true"
    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 612ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deploy/releases/20120809223144 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

any ideas?
if someone needs more info, please let me know
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you are out of memory? Did you take a look at the output of `dmesg`? Perhaps the OOM killer just terminated your rake task?

Comment: what is dmseg? how do I know if OOM is doing this?

Comment: Just ssh into your server and run `dmesg` in the terminal. It will display the kernel logs. If there are any references to `OOM killer`, you ran out of ram. You can also take a look at `free` to see how much ram there is.

Comment: yep, you're right: `[ 3380.091822] Out of memory: Kill process 1075 (ruby1.9.1) score 382 or sacrifice child`

Comment: How do I see which process are consuming more memory?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/102005/how-can-i-display-the-memory-usage-of-each-process-if-i-do-a-ps-ef

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The kernel actively kills processes when RAM is short and processes use to much RAM. You can use `dmesg` to look if the process got killed by the kernel. Messages like this will appear:

```
[ 3380.091822] Out of memory: Kill process 1075 (ruby1.9.1) score 382 or sacrifice child
```

You can activate swap space or shut down other processes. If you are running on a VPS, please make sure you have enough RAM available. The simplest solution - if the problems is really a shortage of free RAM - is just buy more RAM.

Answer (score 9):

I'm running my rails app on Digital Ocean. Creating a 2gb swap seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm on Digital Ocean as well, but what the hell does "Creating a 2gb swap" mean?

Comment: Catfish, you can easily add some swap space like this: "dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/swap.img bs=1M count=1024" This will create an empty file in /tmp/swap.ing of 1G. Then you can call "mkswap /tmp/swap.img" and "swapon /tmp/swap.img"

Comment: I followed this tutorial for my Ubuntu 14.04 droplet. Worked really well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an amazon EC2 micro instance try to delete the old releases of your app and then reboot the server instance. This worked for me.
cap deploy:cleanup
cap rubber:reboot

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error and realized I was storing all my previously releases. I simply used `cap deploy:cleanup` and it worked great.