# Production assets:precompile fails during capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

During deploy, I get the following output:

```
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] executing command
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute assets:precompile
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] 
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute assets:precompile:all
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute assets:environment
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke environment (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute environment
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] ** Execute assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.xx] Killed
```

`bundle -v` output is 1.1.5

The solution I've found is to reboot the server and deploy immediately after. Otherwise, I'm unable to deploy to production and I'm not sure how to debug this issue as there is no output other than it dying on deploy.

Edit: server is running Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar issue today, try the solution for this following question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11893146